# Divide a string in java

Tags: java

I have a sting like this "hello" -- I want to divide the characters into h,e,l,l,o

How can I do this in Java? By using StringTokenizer? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

How about String.toCharArray() ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is ... one char is two byte to contain Unicode characters.

Comment: @cletus: Java strings are sequences of UTF-16 code points: 16-bit values. `char` in Java is 16 bits, not 32 bits. So yes, this approach is potentially problematic if you have characters not in the Basic Multilingual Plane. In most cases this isn't a problem, admittedly.

Comment: FWIW, he asked for a characters, which would be UTF-16, not an int array of Unicode code-points.  Without context as to why he wants it, I gave the obvious answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use the StringTokenizer?

I would read the String API for a method that allows you to get a character from the String.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 

String str = "testing";
String [] temp = null;
temp = str.split("");
for (int i = 0 ; i < temp.length ; i++) {
        System.out.println(temp[i]);
           }
```

Comment: The OP wants the result to be a char array not an array of strings.